# Should I report another account that appears to have been hijacked?

Tags: discussion, users, comment-flags, trolling, reporting

I noticed the following comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844926/is-there-a-known-algorithm-for-finding-the-largest-sub-matrix-with-no-zeros-from)

> No, this cannot be done in Python, but only in Visual Basic. Or in C, using #define 0 1.

I flagged it as:

> This looks to be trolling.  Not only does this have nothing to do with the question, but it proposes doing something no experienced programmer would never do and that could easily cause much confusion and frustration for a beginner.

Looking at the corresponding account, I see that the user has over 17,000 reputation and has given many helpful answers to many questions.  But the profile lists:

> Location: North pole
>   Website: google.com
>   Age: 14

This information seems to imply the account was a legitimate user, but has been hijacked by a troll.  Is there a way to report this?  Should I just ignore it?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an official SE policy on this, but it seems to me that account security is mostly the responsibility of the account owner. If the account is misused, normal moderation activities will eventually take the steps necessary to determine that it does not damage the site. In other words, downvote and flag problematic posts  from this account just as you would any other post.

Comment: I don't think the Location, Website, or age implies anything. Mostly because people are free to put whatever they want there

Comment: Clearly none of those three items are true.  I seriously doubt any 14-year-old would give this answer regarding when to use different clustering algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837622/implementing-k-means-algorithm-jdbc/17845140#17845140 (cue objections), but why would a respected user lie about those things?

Comment: `Is there a way to report this?` Yep, it's in the right hands.  Flagging is the right thing to do here.

Comment: @dspyz The answer you linked was posted 38 minutes ago, so the "real" user appears to be active. When do you suppose that the hijack occurred? Is there a chance that the user was just attempting to post a funny comment on an otherwise useless question?

Comment: yeah, maybe you could be right.  But I don't think the question is useless, I think it's just poorly worded.  I think he's asking how to find the maximal (as in most elements) submatrix (Definition: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Submatrix) where all the elements satisfy some property.  I'd guess that the answer is that it's NP-hard but I don't know for sure.  In any case, that certainly isn't a stupid question.

Comment: @dspyz In response to your comment on that question, the solution in this case is _not_ to "clean up the question." There is nothing to clean up. It is not poorly-worded, as far as I can tell. It is a bad question for the reasons I posted there: No research, no code, and appears to be a "Gimme teh codez" question.

Comment: Different people have different senses of humor. Comments are a place where a bit of humor is sometimes appropriate. Unless you see something *offensive* or inappropriate, then you should flag the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a look at the account, but the telltale signs you cite (like the person's age and location) have not been altered for months, if not years.

Nothing more to see here.

Comment: Then I'm wrong.  I guess the comment was just meant to be a joke and I got over-excited about troll-patrol

Comment: @dspyz You had good reason to be suspicious, however, I would recommend going through the user's activity page before raising alarms. If you find continued evidence, then you may be on to something.